# sonar check jquery code error

Tags: jquery, sonarqube, pmd

**I use sonar to check jquery code, but it always throw an exception:**

```
C:\Documents and Settings\user\.jenkins\workspace\ksp2\ant\sonar_web.xml:31: com.sonar.sslr.impl.LexerException: Unable to lex url: file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/user/.jenkins/workspace/ksp2/WebContent/js/post/viewEditRevisions.js
Caused by: com.sonar.sslr.impl.LexerException: Unable to lex source code at line : 197 and column : 42 in file : file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/user/.jenkins/workspace/ksp2/WebContent/js/post/viewEditRevisions.js
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: None of the channel has been able to handle character '"' (decimal value 34) at line 197, column 42
    at org.sonar.channel.ChannelDispatcher.consume(ChannelDispatcher.java:87)
    at com.sonar.sslr.impl.Lexer.lex(Lexer.java:126)
```

I don't know why. my jquery file is too long, and it throw exception at this line:

```
    var postTemplate = '<h3><div class="title">'+data.postResult.title+'</div></h3><p>'+data.postResult.contentPreview+'</p>'+postTags;
```

I was so confused, I have set encoding as UTF-8, but it still throw exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this way: sonar_web.xml add following code `<property key="sonar.sourceEncoding" value="utf-8" />`

refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15537832/2193246